# login page keeps looping in the back end of TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I have just installed TYPO3 and everything was right with the installation and when the install re-directed me to the backend I type in my credentials and the login just seems to be stuck in a loop.

Any ideas what i can do to get passed this please?

[Login loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQuXO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Open the "LocalConfiguration.php" located in ./typo3conf/ and search for "loginSecurityLevel". If there is "rsa" set it to "normal".

If you want to use "rsa" you need to install "rsaauth" first, after that you can use security level "rsa" again.

Edit:

On standard installations up from version 7.6 LTS, its a standard value in your "LocalConfiguration.php".

Comment: solved, it was the 'rsa' setting changing it to 'normal' worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the backend user credentials and the login form re-appears without any error messages (e.g. "*Wrong username/password*"), make sure:

- the `typo3temp/` directory is writable for the web server user
- the server has sufficient disk space left
- the web server has not ran out of quota (if quotas are configured on the server)
- PHP sessions can be created

Comment: thank you, checked all of the above and if i enter wrong credentials on purpose the same thing happens it just loops.

Answer (score 0):

1. try another browser. same behaviour?
2. check the completeness of your installation: enter the Install_tool and check if all configuration (system environment, folder structure, ...) is green
3. check for cookies and javascript. for a working login you need active javascript and the possibility to store cookies (but that would be needed for the install_tool already)
4. check if you have no further caching installed (just stumbled over a configuration where all access goes through a varnish which does not know about some parameters to switch off caching)

Answer (score 0):

I also changed the loginSecurityLevel to "normal" in the LocalConfiguration.php in the folder typo3conf. That solves the endless loop in the typo 3 login dialog.